# QGIS cannot see PostGIS empty tables

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-3

QGIS didn't load empty tables with geometry columns from Postgresql, showing this error message: "invalid PostgreSQL layer", but when these tables have data it shows it without any problem.

Is it possible to load an empty PostGIS table on QGIS as layers?

The image below shows the same tables in different databases one is with data which is "gui_tool" and the other "test_tool" has no data.

[image]

Comment: I believe it would not be easy because QGIS wants to know some general information about the data source when it opens data. For example the geographic extent of data is NULL if there is no data and it can be hard for QGIS to accept that.

Comment: If there is no geometry, but there is a column of geometry/geog type I have found that they won't display. If you add a feature to one of them (only a value in the geom column), do they show up?

Comment: Might need a valid bounding box

Comment: @DPSSpatial if  data available  in geom, QGIS will show them.

Comment: @Alloylo I think that's the problem...

Comment: QGIS uses metadata for the table to represent it in the browser, so if the table is empty, it will not have metadata.  Is there a reason that you cannot create the table in the structure you want in QGIS as a layer and then transfer it over, or create the table with populated data in PostGIS the first time around?